# Hide "Edit Filter" button on SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I have a report based on a RDL file created in a Visual Sudio Report project using a Microsoft SQL Server data source. The report can only be run on a account's form and shows some entities related to the given account which works fine. However, there is an "Edit Filter" button on top of the report which I want to disable / hide:

[image: edit filter button]

Clicking on the button shows a filter on the current account. I found some solutions online like hacking the viewer.aspx file or creating a parameter in the report and setting its visibility to  hidden or internal (which didn't hide the button).

Is there a supported way to hide or disable this "Edit Filter" button? It's a Dynamics-365 onpremise installation.

Comment: Have you tried some JS? If you can't hide it from ssrs then JS should be able to do it.

Comment: How can I execute JS on the report? Do I need to open the report using a custom ribbon button for this?